# Django: ForeignKey limit_choices_to to equal current object's client

Tags: django, django-models

Given these two models, I want my url FK (in ClientKeyword) to only show the urls whose client equals the current ClientKeyword's client.

What should I put in limit_choices_to?

Right now it looks like this:

```py
class ClientUrl(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(UpstreamClientModel)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True, null=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'url'


KEYWORD_TYPES = (
    ('MN', 'Money'),
    ('BR', 'Brand'),
    ('LT', 'Long Tail'),
)

class ClientKeyword(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(UpstreamClientModel)
    kw_type = models.CharField("keyword type", max_length=2, 
                choices=KEYWORD_TYPES, default='LT')
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    # TODO: keyword parent ManyToManyField("self")
    url = models.ForeignKey(ClientUrl, limit_choices_to={'client': client})
```

I could do the migrations and django didn't complaint, but when I try to add a new keyword form the admin interface I get the following traceback:

```
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  366.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  196.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  209.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  932.         ModelForm = self.get_form(request)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in get_form
  459.         return modelform_factory(self.model, **defaults)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in modelform_factory
  407.     return form_metaclass(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __new__
  206.                                       opts.exclude, opts.widgets, formfield_callback)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in fields_for_model
  164.             formfield = formfield_callback(f, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in formfield_for_dbfield
  107.                 formfield = self.formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in formfield_for_foreignkey
  168.         return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in formfield
  1005.             'queryset': self.rel.to._default_manager.using(db).complex_filter(self.rel.limit_choices_to),
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in complex_filter
  660.             return self._filter_or_exclude(None, **filter_obj)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  642.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1250.                             can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_filter
  1185.                 connector)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in add
  69.             value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in prepare
  320.             return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in get_prep_lookup
  137.             return self._pk_trace(value, 'get_prep_lookup', lookup_type)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in _pk_trace
  210.         v = getattr(field, prep_func)(lookup_type, v, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  310.             return self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/Users/mirkocrocop/.virtualenvs/upstream_backend/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  537.         return int(value)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/clients/clientkeyword/add/
Exception Value: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ForeignKey'
```

Comment: This is an older post (of mine actually) but I think it will get you going in the right direction: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/s9a0J6fKgWs

Comment: thanks, but did you end up using the limit_choices_to option in your models or did you solve it just by writing a custom form? Also,... do you know if it would be possible to update the list of urls depending on the client I select? (for when I'm adding instead of editing)

Comment: I put the filtering logic in a custom form that I used in admin. You should be able to do selective filter for add versus update based on the presence of an `id` on the instance.

Comment: Nice, it did work. However what I meant when I said I wanted the list to be updated when I select the client I meant... that maybe I could do that with some "ajaxy" thing. When I add a new keyword I wouldn't have an instance yet, but once I select the client name from the dropdown, my url's should be updated... maybe you could point me in the right direction. ;-)

Comment: Adding new choices to lists in admin isn't terribly difficult but it can present you with some validation problems. To the best of my knowledge, Django forms won't accept choices that are dynamically added. Showing or hiding choices based on a value in another field is also pretty easy. jQuery is available as part of admin if you're using 1.3 or higher, which gives you pretty much all you'd need to do so.

Comment: so you'd just get the whole queryset and simply modify it via js?

Comment: Correct. To the best of my knowledge, Django won't accept a dynamically added choice as a valid value. So I've just been pulling all of the available choices and then showing/hiding them via JavaScript.

Comment: well, I've been banging my head against the wall for a while and eventually managed to do "almost" what I wanted. I created a view that takes the client id as the input and responds with the list of json objects, and that's what I use to update the options. And I said "almost" because when I select a URL it goes back to showing me the full url list :(... I still have to figure that part out.

Answer (score 7):

Even better: the more "[official](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey)" way to do this is to override `formfield_for_foreignkey()` in your model's admin class.

```
class ClientKeywordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # store the model instance for later
        request.obj = obj
        return super(ClientKeywordAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, 
                                                        **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'url':
            # set the query set to whatever you like
            kwargs['queryset'] = request._obj.client.clienturls.all()
        return super(ClientKeywordAdmin, 
                     self).formfield_for_foreignkey(request, obj, **kwargs)
```