# Django model relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have the models

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class DriverClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)

class Driver(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    driverclass = models.ForeignKey(DriverClass)
```

An event is supposed to have a set amount of `DriverClass`es for the `Driver` to choose from. The problem right now is that a `Driver` is only connected to a `DriverClass` and an `Event`, so when I am choosing a `DriverClass` for the driver in `django admin`, I can choose from all the `DriverClass`es. I am not sure if there is something I can change in my model in order to accomplish what I want, or if I only have to change the `Driver`s `ModelAdmin` class in order to only display the correct Events. What is the correct procedure?

Comment: what is the filter criterial for `Driver` to choose from `DriverClass`?

Comment: The driver is associated with one event, and then the Event's driverclasses.

Comment: I believe your model is ill-constructed. See it like this, you have an `Event`, and an event can have many `DriverClass`es. Fine. Thus a `DriverClass` is already associated with an event, and thus the `Driver`s associated with a certain `DriverClass` are already connected to an event, are they not? I still don't get what you want.

Comment: You are right, and my model might be ill-constructed. I could loose the Driver->Event link and still have the connection in the back, but that is a very weird way of doing it in my opinion. I am simply wondering what the practice is of tieing multiple models together in django.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify a custom `ModelForm` that changes the driverclass field's queryset and add it to your `ModelAdmin`:

```
class DriverForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DriverForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.event: 
            # this form has an event specified in either instance, initial or data
            self.fields['driverclass'].queryset = DriverClass.objects.filter(event=self.instance.event)

class DriverAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = DriverForm
```

One caveat is that when you change the `Event`, the options for your `DriverClass` are not updated until you submit the form. The form will throw a ValidationError, and the form that's returned will have the correct choices. Changing this behavior would require Ajax requests and dynamic updating via Javascript.

Comment: I could to that, is that the regular practice?

Comment: @Martol1ni I guess so, it's regular practice to override a form's `__init__` method for such dynamic, per-instance changes, and I think it's exactly what the field's `queryset` attribute is for.

Comment: @Martol1ni If you're satisfied with this answer, could you please accept it and close this question?

Comment: What happens with the Drivers when one changes the Event of a DriverClass instance? Should the Drivers' `event` change along, should the Drivers' `driverclass` be set to one that is appropriate for its `event` or should the Driver be deleted for not having a legal driverclass, event combination? @Martol1ni

Comment: That is a very good question. I guess I haven't thought this through good enough. The more I think about it, I think I should change to @Chris Wesseling 's answer. It makes more sense to connect it through the driverclass.

Comment: Good point. Looking back at this question, is a DriverClass unique to a single Event? I take it it has something to do with motorsports, shouldn't a DriverClass have a ManyToMany relation with Event? Either way you should figure out what you want when a DriverClass gets changed or deleted.

Comment: In my many attempts to try to redo my model, does anyone have a good suggestion to how the relations should look?

Answer (score 0):

[Games Brainiac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767413/django-model-relationship#comment26095258_17767413) is right. This is what you could model it as, if you insist on having an event property on the drivers:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class DriverClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)

class Driver(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    driverclass = models.ForeignKey(DriverClass)

    @property
    def event(self):
        return self.driverclass.event
```

Just read [Django: ForeignKey limit_choices_to to equal current object's client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590079/django-foreignkey-limit-choices-to-to-equal-current-objects-client), to see that the way you want it is actually the 'weird way'. In the way you want the referential integrity is not guaranteed.